# Randomizing Switch

Tags: c

How can I create a random loop for this code so that it does not do the same case all the time and also this is a function being called in to the main. Hope this helps a bit more i was just thinking of using the rand() function.

```
int escapeRoom()
{ 
    alt_u16 wheels;
    alt_u16 Bumper;
    int i;

        Bumper = IORD_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(EXPANSION_JP1_BASE);
        Bumper = rand() & (LEFT_FRONT_BUMPER | RIGHT_FRONT_BUMPER);   

       switch(Bumper)
        {
            case BOTH_BUMPERS:
            wheels = BACKWARDS;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(EXPANSION_JP1_BASE, wheels);
            break;

            case RIGHT_FRONT_BUMPER:
            wheels = RIGHT_BACKWARDS;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(EXPANSION_JP1_BASE, wheels);
            break;

            case LEFT_FRONT_BUMPER:
            wheels = LEFT_BACKWARDS;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(EXPANSION_JP1_BASE, wheels);
            break;

            case NO_BUMPERS:
            wheels = FORWARD;
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(EXPANSION_JP1_BASE, wheels);
            break;

            for (i=1 ; i<5 ; i++) ;
            {
            IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA(EXPANSION_JP1_BASE, !wheels);
            }  
            break;

        }
}
```

Comment: You know about the C standard library function `rand()`, presumably?

Comment: yes but making a robot escape a room doesnt seem to be as easy as just adding a rand function

Comment: looks odd that you do not have a *break* for case BOTH_BUMPERS, is this intentional? (good to have a comment in the code if so /* fall through*/ ).

Comment: ahhh thats supposed to have a break it does in the original

Comment: @user3481085 Removing the content of the original question will not help future visitors solve their own problems based on your experience.

Comment: StackOverflow has a goal of being a point of reference on anything related to programming -- not only giving you answers to your particular questions but also allowing future visitors to profit from this knowledge base.

Comment: If you've found the answer yourself post it as an answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `Bumper` be random.  e.g. using

```
Bumper = rand() & (LEFT_FRONT_BUMPER | RIGHT_FRONT_BUMPER);
```

Whether that particular statement is right for you depends on what you have in
mind.  For example, I don't know why you do an an initial read from the I/O port.
If you need those bits, then you will need to keep them in some variable other than
your random bumper.

**Update:**  `rand()` can give the same pseudo-random sequence each time.  This might be OK for a robot interacting with an uncertain environment; but in most applicatons you want a random seed.  The easy option is to just call `srand(some unpredictable value such as sensor data or a high-resolution timer)`.   Always I am assuming that you don't Need high Quality randomness.

Comment: What about the seed for `rand()`?

Comment: On a microcontroller, the high-res timer might prove unfeasible for rand() - the µC initialization might very well take the exact same amount of clock cycles each and every time. I'd rather suggest gathering some sensor data.

Comment: That's correct, I will update my update accordingly.  I was thinking of a "wall clock" type timer.  But that makes no sense on a µC and is not likely to be high resolution even if it is.  But overall I doubt the OP cares about the quality of his randomness.